# Terraform acme Error DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge

Tags: terraform

Below is the module.hosted_zones

```
module "hosted_zones" {
  source = "./hosted_zones"
  for_each = var.hosted_zones
  zone = each.key
  records = each.value
  compartment_ocid = "${var.compartment_ocid}"
}


certs = {
  "devtest-oci.example.io" = {
    subject_alternative_names_prefixes = [
      "*",
      "*.apps",
      "*.sys",
      "test"
    ]
  }
}

hosted_zones = {
  "devtest-oci.example.io" = {
    "*.apps." = {
      records = ["1.2.3.4"]
    }
    "*.sys." = {
      records = ["1.2.3.6"]
    }
    "test" = {
      records = ["1.2.3.7"]
    }
  }
}


rovider "acme" {
  server_url = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
}

resource "acme_certificate" "certs" {
  for_each        = var.certs
  account_key_pem = file("${var.acme_account_key_pem}")
  # allow overriding the common name if set
  common_name                   = lookup(each.value, "common_name", null) != null ? each.value.common_name : each.key
  subject_alternative_names     = [for s in each.value.subject_alternative_names_prefixes : "${s}.${each.key}"]
  # recursive_nameservers         = ["169.234.0.2:53"]
  disable_complete_propagation  = true
  min_days_remaining            = 45


  dns_challenge {
    provider = "oraclecloud"
    config = {
      OCI_COMPARTMENT_OCID = "${var.compartment_ocid}"
      OCI_TENANCY_OCID = "${var.tenancy_ocid}"
      OCI_USER_OCID = "${var.user_ocid}"
      OCI_REGION = "${var.region}"
      OCI_PUBKEY_FINGERPRINT = "${var.fingerprint}"
      OCI_PRIVKEY_FILE = "${var.private_key_path}"
    }
  }

  depends_on = [module.hosted_zones]
}
```

I have created a TXT record but I don't have a value of the TXT record. How to get the acme-challenge txt value for the existing domain names? My colleague is able to create new hosted zones, and records, and let's encrypt certs for the same domain(example.io)

Comment: And where is the `module.hosted_zones`? Does the domain you are trying to register exist?

Comment: *.sys.devtest-oci.example.io] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: No TXT record found at _acme-challenge.sys.devtest-oci.example.io
│ [*.apps.devtest-oci.example.io] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: No TXT record found at _acme-challenge.apps.devtest-oci.example.io
│ [devtest-oci.example.io] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.devtest-oci.example.io - check that a DNS record exists for this domain

Comment: Marko E. Yes, it exists. The script created the hosted zones with all records

Comment: Added the module.hosted_zones in code section above

Comment: It works fine if we try to create a cert for the existing zone record. e.g test.abc-oci-poc.example.io

Comment: Not able to create a letsencrypt cert for above hosted zone records